# window.location.replace() - not working as desired

Tags: javascript

My current url is :

```
http://localhost:3001/company/accountingvoucher/1755926b-023c-4944-8200-3402abfeb3d4/yes
```

I want to change the last query paramater from "yes" to "no" on page refresh. For which I am using below code :

```
window.onload = () => {
            let href = window.location.href;
            if (href.match(/yes$/)) {
                href = href.split("yes")[0] + "no";
                window.location.replace(href);
            }
        }
```

The problem is, I need to refresh page twice in order to reload with "no" parameter. On first refresh the parameter continues to be "yes".

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
    //var url = 'http://localhost:3001/company/accountingvoucher/1755926b-023c-4944-8200-3402abfeb3d4/yes'
    var url = window.location.href;
    var isYes = (url.substring(url.length - 3) == 'yes');
    if (isYes){
        url = url.replace('/yes', '/no');
        window.location.href = url;
    }
```